# ProxyPassMatch and mod_rewrite order of operation

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, php-fpm, apache-2.4

I've got a situation with Apache 2.4, PHP-FPM and Wordpress Multi user in sub folder mode.

All non *.php files work fine in the subfolder, as does the main example.com/subblog/ url, however anything with .php in it such as example.com/subblog/wp-login.php is failing with File Not Found from PHP-FPM.

The mod_rewrite file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [PT]
RewriteRule . index.php [PT]
```

Which is basically the recommended file but with some of the [L]'s replaced with [PT] to try and make it work properly.

PHP-FPM is invoked with:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:21358/home/northest/public_html/$1
```

So PHP-FPM is trying to load example.com/subblog/wp-login.php (which doesn't exist) when mod_rewrite is supposed to change it to example.com/wp-login.php (which does exist).

I've read that PT should be used to allow ProxyPassMatch to pick up the rewrite but it still seems like ProxyPassMatch is executing before mod_rewrite gets to it. I turned on mod_rewrite debugging and it wasn't outputting any debug info for *.php files.

What is the solution here to make it always process mod_rewrite rules before the ProxyPassMatch?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. To get it working I had to modify the Rewrite rules somewhat and include them in the Apache config file not via .htaccess.

Apache also started trying to rewrite index.html on to the end of all folders which needed DirectoryIndex to be changed so index.php was at the start.

Finally all the Rewrite rules needed to be absolute with DOCUMENT_ROOT added and rewrites starting with /

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ /$1 [PT]
RewriteRule . /index.php [PT]
```